# popup window Takes two click to open and also with cashed parameters

Tags: asp.net, caching, popup

I have a Button and when I click it a Pop up window opens with some parameters that i pass in it.It takes two click to open it for the 1st time and ever time i open it it will open the window with cashed data and then i have to refresh the data.I need to stop the double click and the cashed issue.Thanks !

Comment: Would you please share the piece of your button code, and the window opener function?

Comment: Selected_Date.OnClientClick = "window.open('Selected_Date.aspx?L=" + Location_Drop.SelectedValue.ToString() + "&M=" + Month_Drop.SelectedValue.ToString() + "&Y=" + Year_Select_Dropdown.SelectedValue.ToString() + "','','scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes, width=550, height=550');";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you put this line in some of your `OnSelectedIndexChanged` events. That is how I managed to replicate the issue. If that is correct, you need to set the auto postback attribute of the dropdownlist to true: `AutoPostBack="true"`

Caching issue can be solved by two approaches:
Put a random querystring value to the opening window.
Or put the `Response.Expires = 0;` line to the Page_Load event of your popup page.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Where did you declare your buttons and dropdownlists? Programmatically in the code behind, or in the design part of your page? I created a blank web site with a single aspx web page, put a dropdownlist and a button, set the autopostback attribute, set button's OnClientClick value in dropdownlist's OnSelectedIndexChanged event, and it worked as expected. So, there must be something different in your code. If you provide your page's sources I can try it myself.

Comment: Bro there is no issue with the drop down .I have a update pannel on the page .